# REST end returns 404 in go version after 1.6

Tags: go, http-status-code-404, upgrade

I upgraded from 1.6 golang to 1.9 (and 1.10) and all REST calls are now returning 404.  They were working fine with 1.6.

main.go

```
import ( "net/http" )

func main() {
   mux := http.NewServeMux()
   handlers.TableHandler(*mux)
}
```

table_handler.go

```
func TableHandler(mux http.ServeMux) {
    mux.HandleFunc("/gpdp/v1/prices/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) 

        log.Println("request for prices: ", r.Method, r.Body)
...}
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of TableHandler? Where and how are you calling ListenAndServe? Although this may not be the cause of the problem, from the snippet there seems to be no reason for you to be passing a value instead of a pointer, and passing a pointer in this case would be, in my opinion, the better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `main` function copies the `mux` value when calling the `TableHandler` function. The `TableHandler` function modifies the copy. This value is discarded on return from the `TableHandler` function.  The result is the handler is not registered in `main()`'s mux.

The fix is to change the `TableHandler` argument type from `http.ServeMux` to `*http.ServeMux`.

```
import ( "net/http" )

func main() {
   mux := http.NewServeMux()
   handlers.TableHandler(mux)  // <--- pass pointer here
}

func TableHandler(mux *http.ServeMux) {  // <--- declare arg as pointer
    mux.HandleFunc("/gpdp/v1/prices/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) 

        log.Println("request for prices: ", r.Method, r.Body)
...}
```

The application stopped working because of a [change to http.ServeMux in 2016](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/8540a1c4dfd6f4950f5a1da6241c76765262ddbd). This change exposed the problem in the application. Copying `http.ServeMux` values was never supported. The `go vet` command prints a warning when `http.ServeMux` values are copied.